# XCode simulator won't run most recent code

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I've been writing an app and I've released one version to the App Store. I've updated it slightly since then and have been playing with it on the Simulator. Unfortunately the Simulator has stopped reacting to the changes in my code. I know it's the simulators fault because if I run the app on my iPad the changes take effect.

I've tried resetting the simulator by going `iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings`, I've tried quitting the Simulator and Xcode.

I have no clue why the Simulator is not working properly. It's just blatantly not updating.

Comment: Clean your project and then build & run

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean your project with <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.
2. Quit Xcode and clean `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` manually. Remove all of its contents.